# Sharepoint 2013 OOB permissions user group

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions, groups, out-of-the-box

I have a simple query. I am Site collection administrator in one SharePoint SC. I created a group as SCA with owner permission. I have an ID which is added to the group by Me . Now when I try to edit permission of another group created by my ID using the other ID it says "You do not have access to view the permissions of this group." So does it mean if a SCA creates a group even an owner of that site will not be able to view or edit the permissions of those groups? Please mind this is only OOB. Any suggestion of why this is and if we can grant permissions to the owners to be able to edit the permissioning of these kind of groups.

Comment: Can you check who is the group owner ? You need to add SCA group as group owner then only you will be able to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add created SCA group as Group owner for newly created SharePoint Permission group. Then only user in SCA group will able edit permission.

Site Action --> Site Setting --> People and Groups under Users and Permissions --> Groups ( will be available in left panel).

There you can edit newly crated group and then add SCA as group owner.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

That may be only because of this setting when you create the group?

[image]

(wanted to add that as a comment, but not sure we can add a picture in a comment).

Comment: I tried this, this option only lets you see who the members are in that group. You can't edit any permissions.